# Extract a tree from a random forest and then use the extracted tree for prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, decision-tree

As an example, let's use the iris data set.

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(iris))
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(iris)), size = smp_size)

train <- iris[train_ind, ]
test <- iris[-train_ind, ]

model <- randomForest(Species~., data = train, ntree=10)
```

If I use the getTree() function from the randomForest package, I can extract, for example, the third tree without any problem.

```
treefit <- getTree(model, 3)
```

But how can I use that (i.e. treefit) to make predictions on the test set, for instance? like "predict()", is there a function out there to do that directly?

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you really want to use that tree, you would have to use the underlying c-code, https://github.com/cran/randomForest/blob/master/R/predict.randomForest.R .. i think the answer using predict.all is a good way around..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `predict` function in the `randomForest` package directly by setting the `predict.all` argument to `TRUE`.

See the following reproducible code for how to use this: also see the help page for [predict.randomForest here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/predict.randomForest).

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(1212)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100, x, 10)
df_train <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
x_test <- rnorm(20)
y_test <- rnorm(20, x_test, 10)
df_test <- data.frame(x = x_test, y = y_test)
rf_fit <- randomForest(y ~ x, data = df_train, ntree = 500)
# You get a list with the overall predictions and individual tree predictions
rf_pred <- predict(rf_fit, df_test, predict.all = TRUE)
rf_pred$individual[, 3] # Obtains the 3rd tree's predictions on the test data
```